# Retrieve value from object in Javascript in XPATH

Tags: html, xpath, xidel

I need to extract information from HTML files. For most of them, I just need to match a particular DOM element's content or attribute, so I use XPATH expressions like `//a[@class="targeturl"]/@href` and the command line tool [xidel](https://github.com/benibela/xidel).

In a different batch of files the information I want is in a `script`, not so readily available:

```
<html>
<head><!-- ... --></head>
<body>
    ...
    <script>
        ...
        var o = {
            "numeric": 1234,
            "target": "TARGET",
            "urls": "http://example.com",
            // Commented pair "strings": "...",
            "arrays": [
               {
                  "more": true
               }
               ,
               { 
                  "itgoeson": true
               }
            ]
        };
    </script>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the object containing the value I want to get is not valid JSON. However, it seems to respect one key-value pair per line.

What can I pass to `xidel --xpath "???"` to get this `TARGET`?

I've tried different thing with XPATH functions but I can't get to a solution without piping to other commands (`match` tells me yes/no, `replace` works line by line..., etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement below XPath:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//script, '"target": '), ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

> What can I pass to `xidel --xpath "???"` to get this `TARGET`?

Since `var o` is actually JSON, I suggest you treat it as such:

```
-e "json(
      //script/extract(
        .,
        'var o = (.+);',
        1,'s'
      )[.]
    )/target"
```

- Extract `{"field1": 1234, "target": "TARGET", "morefields": "..."}` from the `<script>` element node (the json covers several lines, so don't forget the `'s'` regex-flag).
- Interpret the output as json by wrapping `json(` `)` around it (or `//script/...[.] ! json(.)`) and select the `target` attribute.

**[edit]**
To remove the comments (beginning with `//`):

```
-e "json(
      //script/replace(
        extract(
          .,
          'var o = (.+);',
          1,'s'
        )[.],
        '\s+//.+',
        ''
      )
    )/target"
```

Not the most prettiest query, but it works.
**[/edit]**

Comment: > *Since var o is actually JSON*, I suggest you treat it as such
Sadly the real file doesn't really have _valid_ JSON and `xidel` fails to parse it. Nice approach, complete, detailed answer, though.

Comment: Then what does this real file of yours actually look like? I've dealt with invalid JSON before.

Comment: This one has commented lines. It is JavaScript after all, and I can't be sure other batches will have unquoted keys or other offending syntax. I'm updating the question with a more representative sample.